# NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/Sign

Tags: java, mysql

I have been trying a simple program to connect MYSQL to my Java app. I am using Windows OS. I used an online tutorial and tried the following program in notepad:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Database1{
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP";

static final String USER = "root";
static final String PASS = "admin";

public static void main(String[] args) {
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;

try{
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   System.out.println("Connecting to database...");

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

    System.out.println("Creating statement...");
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Employees");

    System.out.println("ID             NAME         ");

    while(rs.next()){
      String id=rs.getString("ID");
      String name=rs.getString("NAME");
      System.out.print(id);
      System.out.println(name);

      }

      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
     } //close try block
    catch(SQLException s){ s.printStackTrace();}
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    finally{

  try{
     if(stmt!=null)
        stmt.close();
   }catch(SQLException se2){
   }// nothing we can do
  try{
     if(conn!=null)
        conn.close();
   }catch(SQLException se){
     se.printStackTrace();
   }//end finally try
   }//end try
   System.out.println("Goodbye!");

   }//end main
}
```

I was getting the error:

```
  C:\JavaP>java -cp .;C:\JavaP\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin-g Database1
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at Database1.main(Database1.java:17)
   Goodbye!
```

After hours of googling and online searching I was finally able to resolve my problem (-when location of java lib folder (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\lib in my case) is maintained in environment variables, none of the java programs could execute.)

But now I am stuck with another issue:

```
 C:\JavaP>java -cp .;C:\JavaP\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin-g.jar Database1
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/Signature
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at Database1.main(Database1.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.lang.Signature
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean about the location of your java lib folder... what did you change? It sounds like really you should have just specified the jar file for MySQL rather than the directory in the first place...

Comment: when i added the C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\lib to CLASSPATH or Path as suggesed by some online, all of my java codes (like as simple as Hello World) started running into error - Class not found. The programs worked only when i removed the lib location entry from my environment variables

Comment: You really don't need to add that to your classpath. Whoever suggested it to you was confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `add` the location of the `jar` file containing the class `org.aspectj.lang.Signature` to your `classpath`

like.

```
java -cp .;C:\JavaP\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin-g.jar;C:\JavaP\aspectj.jar Database1
```

Comment: Thanks Sajan it worked- i downloaded aspectj.jar and it worked.

Comment: Although the code now outputs a lot of crap i am not able to read - so yet to be fixed

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I think you choose the debug version jar for jdbc driver, when I download [MySQL SQL driver jar](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html) and extract the zip file, it looks like below:

[image]

You should choose the jar having the name like `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar` but not `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin**-g**.jar` in debug folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Manifest of the JAR that works:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0

Name: org/aspectj/lang/
Specification-Title: AspectJ Runtime Classes 
Specification-Version: 1.8
Specification-Vendor: aspectj.org
Implementation-Title: org.aspectj.tools
Implementation-Version: 1.8.7
Implementation-Vendor: aspectj.org
Bundle-Name: AspectJ Runtime
Bundle-Version: 1.8.7
Bundle-Copyright: (C) Copyright 1999-2001 Xerox Corporation, 2002 Palo 
  Alto Research Center, Incorporated (PARC), 2003-2009 Contributors. 
  All Rights Reserved.
```